# How to invoke a Cloud Run app without having to add the Authorization Token

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have a cloud run app deployed that is for internal use only.
Therefore only users of our cluster should have access to it.
I added the permission for `allAuthenticated` members giving them the role `Cloud Run Invoker`.
The problem is that those users (including me) now have to add authorization bearer header everytime I want to access that app.

This is what Cloud Run suggests to do (somehow useless when u wanna simply visit a frontend app)

```
curl -H \
"Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" \
https://importer-controlroom-frontend-xl23p3zuiq-ew.a.run.app
```

I wonder why it is not possible to be realized as authorized member like the GCP figures out. I can access the cluster but have to add the authorization header to access the cloud run app as authorized member? I find this very inconvenient.

Is there any way to make it way more fun to access the deployed cloud run app?

PS: I do not want to place the app in our cluser - so only *fully managed* is an option here

Answer (score 1):

You currently can't do that without the Authorization header on Cloud Run.

`allAuthenticated` subject means any Google user (or service account), so you need to add the identity-token to prove you're one.

If you want to make your application public, [read this doc](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/public).

But this is a timely request! I am currently running an experiment that lets you make requests to `http://hello` and automatically get routed to the full domain + automatically get the `Authorization` header injected! (This is for communication between Cloud Run applications.)

Comment: is it this feature that you wanted to talk about on Twitter?

Answer (score 0):

GCP now offers a [proxy tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/services/proxy) for making this easier, although it's in beta as of writing this.

It's part of the `gcloud` suite, you can run:

```bash
gcloud beta run services proxy $servicename --project $project --region $region
```

It will launch a webserver on `localhost:8080`, that forwards all requests to the targeted service, injecting the user's GCP token into all requests.

Of course this can only be used locally.